# Controlling JQuery Animate Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been playing with "marginLeft: "100%"" but that only moves the div off the screen entirely. I want the div, onClick, to float:right against the edge of the right side of the screen.

JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/487r8qza/

HTML

```
<div id="footer">
    <one id="one">

    </one>
    <two id="two">

    </two>
    <three id="three">

    </three>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$("#footer").click(function(){
    $("#one").animate({ 
        marginLeft: "+=900px",
    }, 2000 );
    $("#two").animate({ 
        marginLeft: "+=900px",
    }, 800 );
    $("#three").animate({ 
        marginLeft: "+=900px",
    }, 333 );
});
$("#three").click(function() {
    $("#three").animate({
        marginLeft:  "100%"} , 1000
    );
});
```

CSS

```
#footer {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 115px;
    background-color: #4a4a4a;
}
one {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #070707;
    height: 115px;
    margin-left: -900px;
}
one,two,three {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-family: "Raleway", Arial, Helvetica, Trebuchet MS, Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 115px;
}
one:hover {
    background: black;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 300px;
    height: 115px;
    float: left;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out; 
    cursor: pointer;
}
two:hover {
    background: black;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 300px;
    height: 115px;
    float: left; 
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    cursor: pointer;
}
three:hover {
    background: black;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 300px;
    height: 115px;
    float: left; 
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    cursor: pointer;
}
two {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
    height: 115px;
    margin-left: -900px;
}
three {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #2c2c2c;
    height: 115px;
    margin-left: -900px;
}
```

Comment: I don't know what do you need. However fiddle don't seems to work

Comment: @Marcos Pérez Gude: OP forgot to add the Jquery library in the framework dropdownlist

Comment: Not really sure I understand what you want to do.. You want to, when clicking the footer, that the 3 DIVs slide from the left and stack side by side, and when reaching the side of the screen, they stop sliding. Just staying stacked side by side. is that right?

Comment: Basically the footer has three divs in them which will all reveal content. They're stacked side by side when the come into the screen, and they're all aligned to the left. When I click one of the divs, I want it to move to the right of the screen so I can reveal text. Kind of lik a "Tab" system.

Comment: Ok, so when the the first one is shown, and you click on it, you want the second to slide in. The First one must disappear by sliding to the right then, and must not be visible. Makes sense?

Comment: No, they're all on the screen at once. They're all stacked to the right. Say for example I click the third one, the third one should slide all the way to the right. The area between the second and the third will have text that will be revealed. The problem is, when it slides to the right, marginLeft:"100%" slides it all the way off the screen. I just want it aligned against the right side of the screen.

Comment: okok, hmm, think I get the picture

Comment: I updated the JSFiddle to help you visualize it more, in the results screen you need to expand the view. But you'll see how all three blocks are floated to the left. When I click one of the boxes, I want that box to float to the right, revealing text.

Comment: Oh right, now I get it, thanks, let me check what I can do

Comment: Okay, thanks. Yeah, I've been struggling with this thing forever

Comment: @battlecry12 Before I add a proper answer, tell me if this works out for you. I will then continue on this path and perfect it a bit more: https://jsfiddle.net/gpwexmc6/

Comment: Almost, the boxes should all be aligned to the left. Then, say for example you click "box 1", box 1 should then move to the right.

Comment: Here is the link to a screenshot of what I'm doing

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/t3jwlw4b9givoxc/screenshot.png?dl=0

Comment: Say, for example I clicked "why I accept few clients", that box should move all the way to the right, but not off the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry if it took this long, something came up. Right, so I got it working. Hope this helps

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/IndieRok/raeoe5Lo/1/)

As for CSS, I kept it as simple as possible. The trick here is to make your DIVs display inline-block, so that at the very start, they are neatly stacked next to each other. You will also want to have them all be float right.

CSS:

```
.box-container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 115px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;   
}

.box-item{
    width: 300px;
    height: 115px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.b0{
    background: #7888D9;
}

.b1{
    background: #76D54E;
}

.b2{
    background: #DF7B41;
}
```

Next, in your HTML, you need to give each DIVs the same classname, which will simplify the Jquery click event. Finally, we will also give our first DIV a classname of "current". This will control which DIV must move and which DIV must wait and stay idle as long as the one beside him hasn't moved. You'll understand soon enough.

HTML:

```
<div class="box-container">
    <div class="box-item b0 current">
        Box 1
    </div>
    <div class="box-item b1">
        Box 2
    </div>
    <div class="box-item b2">
        Box 3
    </div>                  
</div>
```

Finally, as for the Jquery, this is where it gets a bit complicated, I'll try to explain the best I can. Bare in mind that math is not quite my forte. Since our DIVS all float right in the CSS, well, they will all be stacked to the right (of course). To counter that and position them to the left, we need to give each DIV a right position. This position will be some kind of offset. To get this number, we need to multiply the width of a DIV by the total number of DIVs. After that, we must subtract this number to the total width of our DIVs' container (basically the browser width).

As for the click event, we must first check if the DIV we clicked has our "current" classname. If it does, we move it, if not, we don't. The easy part is moving them. By resetting a DIV's right value to 0, each one will slide accordingly to the right with our animate event. Once this is done, we switch the "current" classname to the next DIV. We then increment a counter. This will help to see if all DIVs has been moved.

Once all DIVs have been moved to the right, there is an IF statement that will check our counter and see if it is greater than our total number of DIVs. If it is, the sliding motion is inverted and all DIV's will return to the left. In the same manner, if the clicked element is not the current DIV, it will not move. if it is, it will move back to the left. When all DIV's have been move back in default position, ou counter is reset and our "current" classname is reassigned to the very first DIV.

The resize function is not optimal, but it deals with any responsive issue you could face. It will reset all DIVs to the left and recalculate the offset, so that each DIV never slide offscreen. Needs a little work, but it's better than nothing for now.

JQUERY:

```
var $boxWidth;
var $screenWidth;
var $offsetRight;
var $count = 0;

$(function () {

    $boxWidth = $('.box-item').width();
    $screenWidth = $('.box-container').width();
    $offsetRight = $screenWidth - ($boxWidth*$('.box-item').length);
    $('.box-item').css('right',$offsetRight);


    $('.box-item').click(function(event) {

        if($(this).hasClass('current')){            
            if($count < $('.box-item').length){            
                $(this).animate({ 
                    right: "0px",
                }, 2000, function(){                    
                    $count++;                
                    $(this).removeClass('current');                    

                    if($count < $('.box-item').length){
                        $(this).next().addClass('current');
                    }
                    else{
                        $(this).addClass('current');
                    }                                                      
                });                                                        
            }
            else{
                $(this).animate({ 
                    right: $offsetRight,
                }, 2000, function(){                    
                    $count++;
                    $(this).removeClass('current');

                    console.log($count);
                    if($count < ($('.box-item').length*2)){
                        $(this).prev().addClass('current');
                    }
                    else{
                        $(this).addClass('current');
                        $count = 0;
                    }                                                  
                });                                        
            }
        }        
    });

    window.onresize = myResize;
    myResize();
});

function myResize(){
    $screenWidth = $('.box-container').width();
    $offsetRight = $screenWidth - ($boxWidth*$('.box-item').length);

    $('.box-item').each(function(){
        $(this).css('right',$offsetRight);        
    });

    $('.box-item').eq(0).addClass('current');
    $count = 0;
}
```